# Tracking Interactive PDF Clicks

Tags: pdf, analytics

I came across a curious question today, asked by my boss. Is it possible to track the clicks to pages inside an interactive PDF without it being embedded in a web page?

The client wants the user to download a PDF from his/her website and track what pages the user is clicking on inside the downloaded PDF.

After searching around on google for a while all I kept getting was links to pages telling you how to track PDF downloads.

Anyone who can shed some light on this or offer me a definitive yes or no to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javascript for Acrobat API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) makes note of this event (page 368 of the API reference):

```
Page/Open
4.05
This event occurs whenever a new page is viewed by the user and after page 
  drawing for the page has occurred.
The target for this event is the Doc.
This event does not listen to the rc return code.
```

This would imply to me that you can hook this event and (assuming the end user permits the communication) send info to your web server every time they change pages.

Obviously this is limited to when the user is reading in Acrobat (Reader or Professional); it will not work if they are reading directly in Chrome or Firefox.  And to re-emphasize, Acrobat will prompt the user to ask if it is allowed to communicate with an external website. If the user denies it, no tracking.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been stated, the PageOpen event would be the hook for tracking pages. But as this works only for (Acrobat) JavaScript enabled viewers, which at that moment have an internet connection available, those stats would be suboptimal.

We also have to point out that this kind of tracking is highly questionable from the point of view privacy (in Europe, this may even be illegal).

A little bit less questionable could be to chop up the document into single pages, add navigation links, and then use the server stats.